# Clear All recent apps from app on above marshmallow devices

Tags: java, android, rx-java, android-6.0-marshmallow, kill-process

I tried this code but its not working .I am testing it on above marshmallow devices. Does android allow to do this without system app or root

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();
    //get a list of installed apps. 
    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

   for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;
        if(packageInfo.packageName.equals("mypackage")) continue;
        mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);
   }
```

I Also this code part but gives me This Error :

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied

```
try {
                        Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());

                        os.writeBytes("adb shell" + "\n");
                        os.flush();

                        Context newContext = LauncherActivity.this;
                        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) newContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
                        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
                            if (appProcess.processName.equals("packagename")) {
                            } else {
                                os.writeBytes("am force-stop " + appProcess.processName + "\n");
                            }
                        }

                        os.flush();
                        os.close();
                        suProcess.waitFor();

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't get root access2",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't get root access3",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't clear other applications from recent . You can clear or hide only your application from recent.

Comment: No , many other applications manged to do so ,they removes the other apps from recent and clears the memory.